# "Indirect" formula does not seek intervals on separate tabs, any solution?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ok, I'm using the indirect formula, to search for a series of intervals in several tables that are separated into 4 tabs named: "Mês 1,2,3,4", however I intend to pull all the values from the table and then apply the sum, but when I debug the formula it doesn't bring me all the ranges that contain the table values, I wanted to search all the values in the tables according to the criteria range that was selected, when debugging the formula I want the whole range matrix of all values of the tables "Mês 1,2,3,4", any solution ??[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to add *all* the values in a table, not just the top row?

Instead of using a *range* within `INDIRECT`, just use the top cell in the table, then use `SUM(OFFSET())` to add these values.

Something like `SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'" & H15:H18 & "'!$A$2"), 0, 0, 4, 2))`